# Debugging xinetd services with GDB

Tags: gdb, xinetd

I have a xinetd service that runs an executable on client requests.

I want to debug executable.

How to do this in smart way?

Comment: Related: [Automatically connect to a CGI process and break in GDB before it exits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57230391/automatically-connect-to-a-cgi-process-and-break-in-gdb-before-it-exits)

Comment: I like `while true` but it's not very smart as for me.

Comment: If you're on Linux and have systemtap, the other part of that answer (use preattach) should work well.